# How to use JDialog in a Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I want to extend my `JFrame` Form ... with one `JDialog` form (I want to connect with frame,  I want in the menu-bar when someone click to the HELP (from the menu) will show the new dialog box.  I do not want to use `JOptionPane` for this use.

I made in to the program menu with Help menu item, now on the `actionPerformed` will something write.

```
new help(this, true, ).setVisible(true);
```

Something this but I don't remember - what is correct?

Comment: *"but I dont remember how is correct."*  Ask the compiler, consult [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).

Comment: Instead of calling _setVisible_ you can make the _setVisible_ statement at the end of the code and just call the constrcutor as _new help(this, true, )_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using `javax.swing.JOptionPane`? It provides you all you need to show dialogs and prompt the user for inputs.

```
JOptionPane p = new JOptionPane();
// init p
p.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"It provides you all you need"*  No it doesn't.  I'm a big fan of `JOptionPane` (for making SSCCE code), but for some things, you really need a `JDialog`.

Comment: But for most cases, it can accomblish the job.

Comment: *"most cases"*  I agree with that caveat, but it should be an [edit to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16644236/edit) as opposed to a comment.  While you are at it, you might correct the method of displaying the option pane.  I've used 100s (if not thousands) of option panes & never once had to call `setVisible(true)`..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, why hadn't you?

Comment: I must use JDialog           Andrew Thompson: on the JDialog are(had You) setVisible(true)

Comment: *"why hadn't you?"*  What, edited your answer?  I only opened it to correct an obvious (to me) typo.  There is only so far I will edit any question or answer, for fear of writing something the author did *not* mean.  After all, we may just disagree vehemently on the topic.  ;)

Comment: new Help(this, true, ).setVisible(true);                             I used now this. but still not work.   (My JDialog name is Help) Something else is must to set ?

Answer (score 1):

- `this` from `new help(this, true, ).setVisible(true);` could be missinterpreted by another `this` in rest of your code
- create local variable for `JFrame` and `JDialog`, use `title` and `Modal/ModalityType` if is required, e.g. [new JDialog(myFrame, ....)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29)
- create only one instace of `JDialog`, change `DefaultCloseOperations` to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`
- (then only) call `myDialog.setVisisble(true)` delayed inside `invokeLater()` (from `JMenuItems event`)